# How to create a portable document containing .bib references from .(R)md files?

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, markdown

I have a [.Rmd file](https://github.com/npct/pct/blob/master/documents/dd-paper.Rmd) that contains references like `[@smoreda2013spatiotemporal]`. Works great. The problem is that it's referencing a giant [.bib file](https://github.com/npct/pct/blob/master/documents/Transport.bib), making the document less portable.

How to make it portable? So far I see 3 options, each of which as a disadvantage:

- Type references manually (time consuming)
- Create a separate .bib file with only citations used (I don't know how to automate this without a .aux file though)
- Integrate the references somehow in the document (no idea if that's possible)

Comment: What is the problem to share the original bibliography?

Comment: It's way larger (400 kb) and contains more references than it needs to. I could split it, but don't know how automatically using this new-fangled pandoc-citeproc system.

Comment: Since you write in .Rmd you can use the following R-function to clean up your bib-file: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603466/