# pandoc, markdown: create self-contained .bib file from cited references

Tags: bibliographies, knitr, pandoc, markdown, pandoc-citeproc

In Latex there are a variety of tools that can be used to create a self-contained `.bib` file for the
cited references that are extracted from several larger `.bib` files; see [this popular tex.stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/creating-bib-file-containing-only-the-cited-references-of-a-bigger-bib-file).

Is there some way to do this for markdown documents processed by `pandoc` (well, `pandoc-citeproc`)?

**Context**: I'm writing an article (in rmarkdown, `.Rmd` format) shared with a collaborator in the cloud. I refer to several `.bib` files in my local `texmf` tree.

```
bibliography: 
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/statistics.bib"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/graphics.bib"
  - "../localtexmf/bibtex/bib/Rpackages.bib"
```

But my colleague can't access these, unless I copy them to the project directory (and then have to maintain duplicate copies).

The LaTeX solutions rely on the the `.aux` file generated in processing the `.tex` file.  However, `pandoc` does not map `[@reference]` into `\cite` and doesn't produce an `.aux` file.

A similar question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250907/how-to-create-a-portable-document-containing-bib-references-from-rmd-files), but received no answers.

**Update**: There is probably no direct solution with LaTex or `pandoc`, but a first step would be to use `perl` or `sed` to extract all the citation keys, strings like `@key` in the `.Rmd` file.

Answer (score 7):

Recent versions of pandoc allow to do this with a short Lua filter:

```
pandoc --lua-filter extract-bib.lua --to=biblatex paper.Rmd -o paper.bib
```

where `paper.Rmd` is your Markdown input, and `extract-bib.lua` contains

```lua
function Pandoc(d)
  d.meta.references = pandoc.utils.references(d)
  d.meta.bibliography = nil
  return d
end
```

This is the quickest, easiest, and cleanest method, but requires pandoc 2.17 or later.

---

There is also Robert Winkler's perl-based [mdbibexport](https://github.com/robert-winkler/mdbibexport):

> mdbibexport.pl extracts the cited references of a pandoc Markdown document and writes a BibTeX database for this document. The keys are extracted from the Markdown file and written into an auxiliary file, which is used by BibTool to find the references in the bibtex (.bib) data base and to write them into a new file.

---

As a third option, it's possible to combine re-implement the ideas used in mdbibexport with a pandoc Lua writer. E.g., the following will write the reduced bib-file to `bibexport.bib`.  Safe the script below to a file `bibexport.lua` and call pandoc normally, but use bibexport.lua as the target format: `pandoc --to bibexport.lua …`

```
local citation_ids = {}

function Doc(body, meta, vars)
  local citations = {};
  for cid, _ in pairs(citation_ids) do
    citations[#citations + 1] = cid
  end
  -- create a dummy .aux file
  local aux = '\\bibstyle{alpha}\n' ..
      '\\bibdata{' .. meta.bibliography .. '}\n' ..
      '\\citation{' .. table.concat(citations, ',') .. '}\n'
  local auxfile_name = meta.auxfile or 'bibexport.aux'
  local auxfile = io.open(auxfile_name, 'w')
  auxfile:write(aux)
  auxfile:close()
  os.execute('bibexport bibexport.aux')
  return 'Output written to bibexport.bib, aux to ' .. auxfile_name
end

function Cite(c, cs)
  for i = 1, #cs do citation_ids[cs[i].citationId] = true end
  return ''
end

function Str(s) return s end
setmetatable(_G, {__index = function() return function() return "" end end})
```

This should work even with old pandoc versions, but has the `bibexport` tool as an additional dependency.

Comment: This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Although there doesn't seem to be a direct solution yet you could easily establish a workflow using `pandoc`. A possible solution would be:

1. Create a tex-file with pandoc with the `--biblatex` option.
2. Run `latex` once
3. Run `biber --output-format=bibtex file.bcf`

This is not ideal, of course, but if you use a makefile/script the whole process can be easily automated.

With biber, you can also, using tool-mode, perform additional transformations of the datasource, e.g. resolve crossref-inheritances.

Answer (score 0):

Following Denis comment, it makes total sense, it seems that you should do a multistep process and the way you should do it is well explained in this post (external link): https://martinandreasandersen.com/guides/a-nerds-guide-to-writing-papers-for-au/

The only leaving part would be the pandoc command you use to create your .tex document. The complete process would go like this:

pandoc_command example:

```
pandoc yourpaper.md -o yourpaper.tex --biblatex --bibliography=yourpaper.bib --pdf-engine=pdflatex
```

So in your command window or your script, you'd have something like:

```
pandoc_command
latex [yourpaper] # to prepare the document
biber [yourpaper] # to add references
latex [yourpaper] # to collect references
pdflatex [yourpaper] # puts it all together, outputs a pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you write in .Rmd you can use the following R-function to clean up your bib-file:

```
library(stringr)

clean_bib <- function(input_file, input_bib, output_bib){
  lines <- paste(readLines(input_file), collapse = "")
  entries <- unique(str_match_all(lines, "@([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[,\\. \\?\\!\\]]")[[1]][, 2])

  bib <- paste(readLines(input_bib), collapse = "\n")
  bib <- unlist(strsplit(bib, "\n@"))

  output <- sapply(entries, grep, bib, value = T)
  output <- paste("@", output, sep = "")

  writeLines(unlist(output), output_bib)
}
# now call the function
clean_bib(...)
```

Just call it in the setup chunk.

What does the function do? It first searches all citations in the input-file, meaning a string starting with @, containing letters and numbers and ending with a comma, dot, question mark, exclamation mark, space or ] -- adjust this to your needs.

Then it constructs a new bib file only containing these entries.